# Fetch posts that most recently have been commented on

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Im trying to fetch posts that has been recently commented on. But it doesn't return anything at all.

I have a `Post` model with this relation

```
public function comments(){
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }
```

and ofc a `Comment` model with this relation:

```
public function commentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Im trying to return the latest post from a view composer with:

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
    $view->with(['latestCommentedPost' =>
       $this->post->select(['title', 'slug'])->with(['comments' => function($q){
            return $q->latest()->take(6)->get();
        }])
    ]);
}
```

But `$latestCommentedPost` is empty??

### Expected result

Fetch 6 post with the most recent comments.

Comment: 6 posts or 6 comments?

Comment: @TsaiKoga 6 posts, order by latest comments

Comment: try this:`$this->post->select(['title', 'slug'])->with(['comments' => function($q){
            return $q->latest()->take(6)->get();
        }])->take(6)->get()`

Comment: @TsaiKoga It returns `Post` by the ID column

Comment: so you want the posts order by latest comment too?

Comment: Yes i want 6 post, ordered by latest comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order by the most recent comments, you need to use the `created_at` from `commentable` or `comments` table. They are from different tables.

You need to leftjoin a `commenttable` which have max `created_at` , so you can sort by the recent comments.

```php
public function compose(View $view)
{
    $view->with(['latestCommentedPost' =>
       $this->post->select(['posts.title', 'posts.slug'])
        ->leftjoin('commentable', function($join) {
            $join->on('commentable.commentable_id', '=', 'posts.id')
                 ->where('commentable.commentable_type', 'App\Post')
                 ->latest()->limit(1);
        })->latest('commentable.created_at')
        ->take(6)
        ->with(['comments' => function($q){
            return $q->latest()->take(6)->get();
        }])->get()
    ]);
}
```